# Inject articles directly in BD - OTRS

Tags: otrs

When I inject some items directly into a certain ticket through the database, those notes do not appear when I access the ticket through the application. Later, when I create a note for that ticket through the application, the notes I created through the database appear. Can someone help me please?

It appears that there is some type of pointer to the last article, and, in the application, only appears the articles created before that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the ticket has been accessed the first time, then the ticket data is saved in a cache file. Cache files are deleted as soon as you change something in the ticket via the API and then renewed. You would have to clear the cache for that ticket, or the cache in general to get the current DB state.

```
sudo -u otrs perl /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl Maint::Cache::Delete
```

You should use the API or a webservice instead of writing data into the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already saw in some foruns that I should be using the genericInterface API, but I find it hard to get some examples of it working... Will keep searching, ty :)

Comment: Use discord and search for the znuny discord server. There are plenty of people who can help you with the generic interface. You can also use the znuny forum or create a new question here if you have problems with the generic interface.

Comment: @sergionunes would you be so kind to accept my answer, if it did answer your question? :)